# There is a error occur between the coding of html img tag can not place the image in ce

Tags: image

When I write this .**header{ text-align:aqa centre;}** then, the result is not setup the image in centre....

**.header{ text-align: centre ;}**
By using this code on css the result will become to settle the image in centre but I can't find the result....